# Issue with unix sort

Tags: linux, unix, sorting

This is more of a doubt than a question.

So I have an input file like this:

```
$ cat test
class||sw sw-explr bot|results|id,23,0a522b36-556f-4116-b485-adcf132b6cad,20130325,/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[4]/div/img
class||sw sw-explr bot|results|id,40,30cefa2c-6ebf-485e-b49c-3a612fe3fd73,20130323,/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[8]/div/img
class||sw sw-explr bot|results|id,3,72805487-72c3-4173-947f-e5abed6ea1e4,20130324,/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[20]/div/img
```

Kind of defining the element in an html page.
The comma separated 5 columns can be considered.

I want to `sort` this file with respect to the second column, i.e. columns having 23,40,3.

I am not sure why `unix` `sort` isn't working.

These are the queries I tried, surprisingly none gave me desired result.

```
cat test | sort -nt',' -k2

cat test | sort -n -t, -k2

cat test | sort -n -t$',' -k2

cat test | sort -t"," -k2

cat test | sort -n -k2
```

Is there something about `sort` that I don't know?

This didn't cause me a problem as I separated the columns, sorted, then joined again. But why did not `sort` work??

NB:- If I remove $3 of this file and then sort, it works fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this line should work for you:

```
sort -t, -n  -k2,2 test
```

- you don't need `cat test|sort`, just `sort file`
- the default END POS of `-k` is the end of line. so if you `sort -k2` it means sort from the 2nd field till the end of line. In fact you need sort by **exact** the 2nd field. And this also explains why your sort worked if you removed 3rd col.

if test with your example:

```
kent$  sort -t, -n  -k2,2 file
class||sw sw-explr bot|results|id,3,72805487-72c3-4173-947f-e5abed6ea1e4,20130324,/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[20]/div/img
class||sw sw-explr bot|results|id,23,0a522b36-556f-4116-b485-adcf132b6cad,20130325,/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[4]/div/img
class||sw sw-explr bot|results|id,40,30cefa2c-6ebf-485e-b49c-3a612fe3fd73,20130323,/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[8]/div/img
```

Comment: Hey can you please explain why other `sort` commands didnt work even when they work elsewhere??

Comment: @rohitvk I added an explanation. check if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here comes a working solution:

```
cat test.file | sort -t, -k2n,2
```

Explanation:

```
-t,    # Set field separator to ','

-k2n,2 # sort by the second column, numerical
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-k2n,2` to sort only on the second field instead of from the second field to the end of the line?

Comment: @Kent I've tested it with the example data, but I think Frederic is right, thanks! :) (althought it doesn't matter in this case)

Comment: Yes, as I said, it doesn't matter in this case

Comment: thanks now it does. Your previous version, b4 editing I tried. Not this one. Now it works! And I also understood how. Thanks @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: This first one should have worked for *your special data* as well.. But there would be unwanted side effects if, for example two rows would contain `40,1...` and `40,2...` they would get sorted by the text after the `,` and this isn't expected. That's why `k2n,2` instead of `k2n` :)